# Website cutting off on the right on mobile devices (desktop view)

Tags: html, css, mobile

My issue is 1/8 of the website it cut off on the right side when viewed on any mobile device, and I am not sure how to fix it.

Website: http://www.spotlightoutlet.com/

SS on mobile: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/47703905/screen.png

This might be an unusual question as my client refuses to have a responsive mobile friendly stylesheet for her website. She just the website to look like how it does on desktop.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No need to change the title to solved, when you provide the check mark, there is an indication that an answer is picked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of your elements are overflowing the wrapper/container div.

Try setting this meta tag in `<HEAD></HEAD>` to instruct mobile how to size the viewport:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1060px, maximum-scale=1.0" />
```

Change `1060px` according to your actual dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it's because `.container` has a fixed width: `width: 1200px`.

Try this:

```
.container {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1200px;
}
```

Comment: this made all the previously cut off content pushed to the next line... but it's all good now, <meta name="viewport" content="width=1060px, maximum-scale=1.0" /> fixed it. thanks for your help =)